# AIX hdisk creation

Tags: aix

I am new to networking and am trying to implement power HA in an AIX environment. As a pre requisite I need my rootvg which is hdisk0 and another 3 additional hdisks, which will be hdisk1, hdisk2 & hdisk3. I am a little confused and wanted to know how I can add these hdisks in, is it a physical dick which needs to be added or can I create a dummy or something. When running the command lspv hdisk0 is returned.

Comment: Do I request for the IT guy to add in physical disks in order to get them when the command lspv is run ?

Comment: I want an output from lspv like this   # lspv
hdisk0     00c609e0a5ec1460         rootvg     active
hdisk1     00c609e037478aad         None
hdisk2     00c03b1a32e50767         None
hdisk3     00c03b1a32ee4222         None

Comment: but what I get is this # lspv
hdisk0          00c0c356c313ed35                    rootvg          active

Comment: Why do you need four PVs?

Comment: Its listed as a pre requisite for running power HA, as I will need to assign resource groups to them.

Comment: Are you sure about that? When I took a peek at the installation guide it said that _volume groups_ get assigned to resource groups. If I were you I would edit your question and describe more of how you have planned the cluster (e.g. concurrent or nonconcurrent storage, what exactly the storage _is_, and anything else that might be relevant).

Comment: When I had tried it out in a simulated environment which was made available, it had these hdisks and in the guide also. I m only wondering what these hdisks represent and if it is possible to work without them ? This is my first time doing this and i m quite lost. I m wondering on the 2 points I mentioned above

Comment: Is it possible to work without them ? and are they physical disks ?

Comment: I don't know what your disks are. You're more likely to know than I am. If they're on a storage server connected to a SAN then the storage server handles redundancy and you only need one PV anyway (provided it's large enough for whatever your applications need). Are you sure you're using [the official IBM documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPHQG_7.1.0/com.ibm.powerha.navigation/powerha_pdf.htm)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22824/discussion-between-user2586302-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question. hdiskX devices on AIX represent physical disks, those physical disks can be internal disks (SCSI, SAS, etc) or SAN attached disks or virtual SCSI disks if you are using VIO virtualization. You cannot just create dummy hdiskX devices and expect Power HA to use them.  
For you to be able to "see" the additional hdiskX devices in your server, you will need to physically add the drives to the server, or allocate additional SAN LUN's or virtual SCSI disks to it, and then run the <kbd>cfgmgr</kbd> command in AIX to discover them.